# EF Calls Stored Procedure that returns Associated Records

Tags: entity-framework

Riddle me this: I have a stored procedure `GetTeamAndPlayers`

```
SELECT * 
FROM Teams 
INNER JOIN Players ON Teams.Id = Players.TeamId 
WHERE Teams.Id = @TeamId
```

I have a database-first EF6 context with `Team` and `Player` entities, `Team` of course has a navigation property to `Player`.

The question: can my procedure `GetTeamAndPlayers` return a `Team` with associated `Player` navigation already populated (without lazy loading)?

I am trying to get a stored procedure to return something like:

```
Team team = context.Teams.Include(t => t.Players).Single(t => t.Id == Id);
```

What do you think you brilliant devs?

Thanks in advance!